# Local hyperlinks broken after PDF processing with Ghostscript

Tags: hyperref, ghostscript

I usually compress my `tex` PDFs with `ghostscript`:

```
pdflatex -shell-escape file.tex

gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite        \
   -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4   \
   -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress      \
   -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH      \
   -sOutputFile=file_compressed.pdf \
    file.pdf
```

Normally that works well, but if I have relative links to local files, the links don't work afterwards.

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \href{run:./audio.mp3}{test}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The link works in `file.pdf` but not in `file_compressed.pdf`. Is there any `pdflatex` or `ghostscript` setting that retains the link in the compressed version?

I use Acrobate Reader 10.1.14 for viewing, Ghostscript 9.10 and pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (TeX Live 2014) on OS X 10.9.5.

---

**Update:** The breakage of hyperlinks had nothing to do with *compressing* the PDFs. The breakage happened for **all** re-processing of PDFs containing hyperlinks in its input PDF.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Use the Ghostscript option "`-dPrinted=false`" or the hyperref option "pdfa":
`\usepackage[pdfa]{hyperref}`.

You can find more info in this post:

[Set the print flag on links with hyperref to preserve them with ghostscript >= 9.25](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/456896/set-the-print-flag-on-links-with-hyperref-to-preserve-them-with-ghostscript-9)

Comment: The `-dPrinted=false` ghostscript option will have the effect to drop print annotations, so that's a bad idea in general. Thus `\usepackage[pdfa]{hyperref}` is probably a better solution if it has no side effects.

Comment: The `pdfa` hyperref option is actually a bad idea: if used, when the PDF file is printed, the boxes around the links are printed, making the document less readable.

Comment: @vinc17 what are "print annotations"??

Comment: @pluton See [general information about annotations](https://pspdfkit.com/blog/2018/what-are-annotations/); there is also a link to the PDF specifications. About the annotation flags, see Section 8.4.2. For instance, an annotation can have the _Print_ and _NoView_ flags set, in which case the annotation will be printed, but not displayed on screen. If the _NoView_ flag is set and `-dPrinted=false` is used, then the annotation will be dropped by Ghostscript, according to [Ghostscript bug 699830 comment #16](https://bugs.ghostscript.com/show_bug.cgi?id=699830#c16).