# Ghostscript breaks the hyperlinks of my PDF

Tags: pdftex, ghostscript, ps2pdf

When I use Ghostscript on a PDF it breaks the PDF's hyperlinks. Why, and how can I retain hyperlink functionality after doing so?

I have made a PDF named `link.pdf` with the text `Hello World` where `world` is linked to https://www.bbc.com. I tried this beginning with both LibreOffice Writer and LaTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}

Hello \href{https://www.bbc.com/}{World}.

\end{document}
```

The link works.

Now execute

```
$ gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite \
     -dNOPAUSE         \
     -dQUIET           \
     -dBATCH           \
     -dPDFSETTINGS=/ebook \
     -sOutputFile=link-export-gs.pdf \
      link.pdf
```

The link is broken.

Edit1: Originally asked about Ghostscript and ps2pdf. Given @AlexG's comments, removed ps2pdf.

Edit2: Note, the reason I wish to do this is to utilise Ghostscript's `-dPDFSETTINGS=/ebook` compression, so I added that to the command.

Comment: Why would one want to run `ps2pdf` on a PDF?

Comment: Good point. I just thought it was a simpler syntax for saying a similar thing as the ghostscript command, given that ps2pdf utlises gs. Maybe that adds confusion and I should remove it?

Comment: `ps2pdf`, as its name suggest, is primarily for PS to PDF conversion. If you produced a PS file from your source using `latex` (instead of `pdflatex`) and `dvips` via an intermediate DVI file, then running `ps2pdf` would make sense. It would indeed create a clickable link from the  `pdfmark` specials inserted by the `hyperref` package. Running `ps2pdf`on a already interactive PDF kills all interactivity therein. So, there is really no point in doing this.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Will remove ps2pdf from this question.

Comment: maybe try this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/458631/36296

Comment: @DavidCarlisle -  Hyperref (version 1.2 anyway) is dated 2002, but after reading page 37 I see your point.

Comment: Thank you @samcarter, that lead me to the right answer.  It was just a case of adding the `pdfa` when loading package `hyperref`. If you would like to write that as an answer I'd be happy to tick it as done. Or maybe this whole thread should rather be marked as a duplicate.

Comment: @kokoro Great to hear that you were able to solve your problem! I voted to close as duplicate because I don't think I could give any more useful information in an answer.

Comment: @samcarter Definitely the right way to go. Thanks for everyone's help!

Comment: You have to   (1) Use Ghostscript ***v9.25 or newer***, and   (2) Add the parameter ***`-dPrinted=false`*** to your Ghostscript command line in order to preserve hyperlinks in the PDF output.